# What are the ways to declare a class that cannot be instantiated?

Tags: c#, .net, class, instance, instantiation

What are the ways to create a non-instantiable class? One way is by declaring it as an abstract class. Is it possible to do it by making the class constructor as private? Is a sealed class, non-instantiable?  And, are there any other ways to do it in C#?

Comment: what do you want to do with the class?

Comment: Answer = Static class

Comment: Abstract class,static class they cannot be instantiated

Comment: @MajkeloDev     Thanks. But If the class constructor is Private, can't we create an instance of that class?

Comment: with private constructor it is still possible to  instantiate class but only inside it self

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ... and via reflection. There is nothing stopping people from instantiating it except mere convenience. If you want to make it impossible, abstract or static is the way to go.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Marking a class as abstract or static (they are mutually exclusive) are the only two ways. Marking all constructors as private does not make the class uninstantiateable since the class can still construct itself, and others might be able to do it via reflection.

Comment: Is a sealed class, non-instantiable?

Comment: @madmax sealed class is non-inheritable.

Comment: No, a sealed class cannot be inherited. It says nothing about instantiateability

Comment: But a sealed class that can not (normally) be instantiated is an oxymoron. What would it be good for?

Comment: @kai           What is reflection?

Comment: Reflection is a way of programatically accessing information about types and assemblies. It can be used to get type information, dynamically creating objects, accessing private members and so on. You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ms173183.aspx

Comment: throw exception in a constructor will make class non instantiateable

Answer (score 2):

As answered by others abstract and static classes cannot be instantiated however a class with private constructor can be by using a public member function. This is how the [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern works

Answer (score 2):

Only `static` looks like complete solution here because `abstract` class still can be instantiated when class instance that inherits from it is instantiated. Consider the scenario :

```
abstract class A {  }

class B : A {  } 

somewhere in code :

B instance = new B();  // this creates instance of class A as well
```

P.S.
At first i though that `abstract sealed` might be solution for this problem as well but it doesn't make much sense to use such a construction so it doesn't even compile :

```
Error   1   'A': an abstract class cannot be sealed or static   D:\Projects\TEST\Testapp\Program.cs 15  27  ITT.Domain
```

Comment: I agree. In .Net you can get a Stream instance. Of course that will always be an instance of a subclass of Stream. But for the code both inside the Stream class and outside the Stream class the instance is still an instance.

Comment: What is abstract sealed? Can someone explain what it is?

Comment: nice mentioning it but abstract sealed is not possible.

Comment: I believe that `abstract sealed` will not event compile.

Comment: Might just be arguing semantics now, but according to MSDN: "An abstract class cannot be instantiated. The purpose of an abstract class is to provide a common definition of a base class that multiple derived classes can share." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx

Comment: That is, you are not constructing an A. You are constructing B. B might inherit from A, and you can cast B to A and treat it as one, but it IS not an A.

Comment: `static` in C# compiled as `abstract sealed` in MSIL.

Comment: I know that but from practical point of view marking class as `abstract` still allows user to control when it is instantiated (when derived class instance is created) and with `static class` it is not the same. Static class instances are created only once on app start and user has no control over it (which is just what OP wanted)

Comment: @Fabjan well to be fair, what OP wanted to know was "What are the ways to create a non-instantiable class?" According to MSDN, marking it as abstract is one way to accomplish this. Whether an abstract or a static class is best for OPs use-case (if indeed there is one, and it's not just for educational purposes) is not clear by the question. One possible advantage of an abstract class over a static one is control of life-cycle and having state. Access can be provided to clients by factory methods and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**internal classes** are only visible inside of your assembly and therefore cannot be instantiated outside of this assembly.

But as far as i know, you could still create an instance via reflection.
you can disable reflection via [ReflectionPermission Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.reflectionpermission.aspx)

As mentioned above you could declare it as **abstract** or add an abstract method.

If you just want to declare a contract, you could use an interface, but that's not a class at all.

**sealed** means you cannot inherit this class

**singleton** classes can only be created once per application
[singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

see [sealed (C# reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx)